# Does this two-token scheme work?

Tags: authentication, web-application, jwt

Security noob here. I've been trying to figure out how to secure my web app from both CSRF and XSS. It's a single-page app that talks to a JSON API on the server side.

I'm trying not to do a roll-your-own scheme, but haven't had much luck finding one that does not have the complexity of OAuth.

Here's my proposed scheme:

When the user logs in, the server sends back two tokens. Each token is a JWT.

```
JWT 0: username + nonce0 + nonce1, signed.
JWT 1: username + nonce0 + nonce2, signed.
```

The tokens are generated in pairs. They share the first nonce, but the second must be different.

The first one gets sent back in JSON, and must be sent in future requests as a bearer token.

The second one gets sent back in an httponly cookie.

For a request to be valid, it must see both tokens, the signatures must be good, the first nonce must match and the second one must not match.

I'm thinking this scheme isn't vulnerable to CSRF, because an attacker won't see the bearer token. It won't be vulnerable to XSS 
because an attacker won't see the httponly token. An attacker won't be able to guess the missing token because of the second nonce.
An attacker won't be able reuse tokens because of the first nonce. An attacker won't be able to generate tokens because they're signed.

Does this scheme work?

Comment: Have you tested it? I wonder how the browser will know how to generate and send these tokens.

Comment: The server generates the tokens, not the browser. Browser just sends them back.